# How to add row to DataGridView then Load data from database in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Sorry if i am unable to specify exactly what i want but please understand the idea.

[Image of software which i am programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDSzD.png)

I had products on a panel and when a product is clicked i want to add that product item code to 1st column of datagrid view and get the remaining data automatically from database.

I want a function of AddToGridView(int productid) when product id is passed it should get the remaining details automatically. The datagrid is working fine with manual entries but i am unable to add row with product id and get its remaining data when clicked on product image.

Please help thanks

Here is my current piece of code

```
private void MainGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string newvalue;
                newvalue = (MainGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value).ToString();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name,saleprice from Products where productid='" + newvalue + "'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = 1;
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = 0;
                con.Close();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MainGrid.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[5].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[3].Index].Value));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = "";

                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Product does not exists");
            }
        } else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                string newvalue;
                newvalue = (MainGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value).ToString();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT productid,saleprice from Products where name like'" + newvalue + "%'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = 1;
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = 0;
                con.Close();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MainGrid.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[5].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[3].Index].Value));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = "";
                MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = "";

                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Product does not exists");
            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MainGrid.Rows)
            {
                double total = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[3].Index].Value));
                double discount = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[4].Index].Value);
                total = total - discount;
                row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[5].Index].Value = total;

            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MainGrid.Rows)
            {
                double total = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[3].Index].Value));
                double discount = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[4].Index].Value);
                total = total - discount;
                row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[5].Index].Value = total;
            }


        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MainGrid.Rows)
            {
                double total = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[3].Index].Value));
                double discount = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[4].Index].Value);
                total = total - discount;
                row.Cells[MainGrid.Columns[5].Index].Value = total;

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: What are columnIndexes are used for? Please explain. Additionally, you can bind the DataTable directly to DataGridView. Please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Comment: You've provided the CellEndEdit, which you say is working fine. Where's the function AddToGridView that you're tying to fix?

Comment: column indexes used for are 0 for item code 1 for product name 2 for quantity 3 for sale price 4 for discount and 5 for total amount

Comment: I can't bind the DataTable directly because i want to add a productid to datagridview when an image of product is clicked and load its details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting that image; very helpful.  I think it should be done like this.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try and feed back.